# How can i use PHP 8.1 syntax in VSCODE?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, php-8, php-8.1

I have PHP 8.1.4 installed on my PC on a C drive

but I have XAMPP in drive D which have all my PHP files and I have PHP 8.1.2 in XAMPP

I have PHP Intelephense installed on my VSCODE and I disable PHP Language Features

but still when I write PHP 8 or 8.1 syntax my vscode show error

[image]

Comment: Can you give a specific example,?

Comment: When you say drive C and drive D, you mean you have 2 operating systems installed?

Comment: NO, we don't have 2 operating systems its 2 portion

Comment: I add the SS now

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify your PHP version for the PHP intelephense extension.

2 ways to do that :

- Settings > Preferences and typing "intelephense php version" and then yo can set `8.1.*`  instead `8.0.0` here :

[image]

- edit your VSCODE `settings.json` with this : `"intelephense.environment.phpVersion": "8.1.*"`.

**NB : check if you have the lastest version of `PHP Intelephense` it also very important!**

And that's it !

Comment: It is already set   
"intelephense.environment.phpVersion": "8.1.4",
"php.executablePath": "D:/xampp/php/php.exe",
"files.associations": { "*.module": "php" },


and i don't have paid PHP Intelephense i use free version

Comment: I have v1.8.2 of PHP Intelephense

Comment: It's very strange because it's works for me with PHP 8.1.7 and a free version. Have you already try to reinstall the extension ? Do you have any other settings related to PHP in your settings.json?  What version of PHP Intelephense do you have (I have 1.8.2)? **Also update your VsCode to latest (important) !**

Comment: I have the latest version of vscode and PHP Intelephense

Comment: VSCODE version 1.68.1 and PHP Intelephense 1.8.2

Comment: Mystery then ... Except uninstalling the extensions or the editor to start from scratch I personally don't see any solution, sorry :/

Comment: I had installed a PHP extension which caused this error now the problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

**Note there are 2 type of settings** - one is the "main" for the **User** and secondary for the **Workspace**, the workspace has higher priority.

1. Set the PHP version by setting the PHP executable in the PHP built-in extension settings

   - Extensions => PHP => PHP > Validate: Executable Path
   - you will most likely have to set this through the "Edit in settings.json"
   - the modification will look like `"php.validate.executablePath": "/usr/bin/php8.2"`

     - of course replace `/usr/bin/php8.2` with your own path to PHP exe
     - if you're struggling on Windows, you can download specific version of PHP into a custom directory from https://windows.php.net/download and link the `php.exe`
2. Set the PHP version for the PHP Intelephense extension in the settings:

   - Extensions => intelephense => Intelephense > Environment: PHP Version

     - here you only pu in the version itself e.g. `8.2.0`

Also note that if you have broken PHP file completely, some errors may not be shown at first - like a wrong named argument - which is not exactly a syntax error but is validated later if there are not previous syntax errors (like "PHP Parse error..." etc...

Also see: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/php for more information on how VSCode itself does the linting.